# JTabbedPane: Actions performed before displaying selected tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

When one of the panels present in a `JTabbedPane` is clicked, I need to perform a few actions at the start. Say, for example, I need to check the username and password. Only if those match, the particular panel operations need to be performed. Can you suggest any methods?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but I would do something like:

- Add a ChangeListener to the JTabbedPane to listen for the first tab click.
- When a ChangeEvent occurs perform the login on a background thread using a SwingWorker.
- If the login is successful perform the required UI operations on the Event dispatch thread.

For example:

```
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    private boolean init;

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if (!init) {                                        
            init = true;

            new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    try {
                        boolean loggedIn = get();

                        if (loggedIn) {
                            // Success so perform tab operations.
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace(); // Handle this.
                    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace(); // Handle this.
                    }
                }

                protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    // Perform login on background thread.  Return true if successful.
                    return true;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The action to change the tab is triggered by a mouse listener in the UI class. it goes through and checks whether there is a tab at the clicked coordinate and if so, whether the tab is enabled.  If that criteria is met, it will call `setSelectedIndex(int)` on your `JTabbedPane`.  In order to intercept the tab changing, what you can do is override `setSelectedIndex(int)` to trigger a permissions check.  Once the permissions are validated, you can make a call to `super.setSelectedIndex(int)`.  this should do what you want.

please note that if the permissions check is a long running call (ie a call to a database or a server), you should use something like a [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) break up your processing, so that the permissions check is done off the `AWT EventQueue` and the call to `super.setSelectedIndex(int)` is done on the `AWT EventQueue`.